# A table's crud operations and local storage in jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, function, local-storage, crud

I build a table with CRUD actions using jQuery. It is necessary to keep all uploaded data in local storage. If I make any changes to the table, the local storage ought to update.
The Edit, Delete, and Update functions all performed as intended in the created row.
I get a new row when I click the "Add New" button. However, when I clicked again, it failed to add a new row. Please help me to solve this problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>CRUD Table jQuery</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 text-right">
                <input type="button" id="btnAdd" class="btn btn-primary para" value="Add New" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row pt-3">
          <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 p-2 ">
            <table id="tblData" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
              <thead>
                <tr id="headings">
                  <th class="schedule-color heading">ID</th>
                  <th class="schedule-color heading">Name</th>
                  <th class="schedule-color heading">Address</th>
                  <th class="schedule-color heading">Age</th>
                  <th class="tdaction">Action</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody class="searchable">
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>      

    <script>
        $(function() {
            var myEmptyRow = [{
                class: "tdID", content: $("<input>", { type: "text", class: "form-control txtID" })
            }, {
            class: "tdName", content: $("<input>", { type: "text", class: "form-control txtName"})
            }, {
            class: "tdAddress", content: $("<input>", { type: "text", class: "form-control txtAddress"})
            }, {
            class: "tdAge", content: $("<input>", { type: "text", class: "form-control txtAge" })
            }, {
            class: "tdAction",
            content: [
            $("<button>", {
                class: "btn btn-sm btn-success btn-save"
            }).html("Save"),
            $("<button>", {
                class: "btn btn-sm btn-success btn-cancel"
            }).html("Delete")
            ]
            }
            ];

            var myButtons = {
                edit: [
                $("<button>", {
                    class: "btn btn-success btn-sm btn-edit"
                }).html("Edit"),
                $("<button>", {
                    class: "btn btn-danger btn-sm"
                }).html("Delete")
                ],
                update: [
                $("<button>", {
                    class: "btn btn-success btn-sm btn-save"
                }).html("Update"),
                $("<button>", {
                    class: "btn btn-danger btn-sm"
                }).html("Delete")
                ]
            };

            function getStore(index) {
                console.log("Get data for " + index);
                return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(index));
            }

            function saveStore(index, data) {
                console.log("Saving Data to " + index, data);
                localStorage.setItem(index, JSON.stringify(data));
            }

            function deleteStore(index) {
                console.log("Deleting Data for " + index);
                localStorage.removeItem(index);
            }

            function addRow(target, data, empty) {
                if (target == undefined) {
                target = $("table:eq(0)");
                }
                if (empty == undefined) {
                empty = false;
                }
                if (data == null) {
                return false;
                }
                console.log("Add Row to " + target.attr("id"), empty);
                if (empty) {
                $("tbody", target).html("");
                }
                var row = $("<tr>").appendTo($("tbody", target));
                if (data == undefined) {
                // Add Empty Row
                $("<td>", {
                    colspan: 4,
                    class: "text-center"
                }).appendTo(row);
                } else {
                row.addClass("trNewRow");
                $.each(data, function(i, cell) {
                    $("<td>", {
                    class: cell.class
                    }).append(cell.content).appendTo(row);
                });
                }

                console.log(data, data.length);
                if (data.length == 4) {
                $("<td>", {
                    class: "tdAction"
                }).append(myButtons.edit).appendTo(row);
                }
                return row;
            }

            function saveRow(row) {
                if (row == undefined) {
                    return false;
                }
                var rowData = [{
                    class: "tdID",
                    content: $(".txtID", row).val()
                    },{
                        class: "tdName",
                        content: $(".txtName", row).val()
                    }, {
                        class: "tdAddress",
                        content: $(".txtAddress", row).val()
                    }, {
                        class: "tdAge",
                        content: $(".txtAge", row).val()
                    }
                ];
                $.each(rowData, function(i, c) {
                $("." + c.class, row).html(c.content);
                });
                $(".tdAction", row).html(myButtons.edit);
                saveStore("row-" + row.index(), rowData);
            }

            function init() {
                if (localStorage.length == 0) {
                addRow($("#tblData"));
                } else {
                console.log("Found Local Storage. Rows: " + localStorage.length);
                $.each(localStorage, function(k, o) {
                    var rowData = getStore(k);
                    console.log(k, rowData);
                    addRow($("#tblData"), rowData);
                });
                }
            }

            init();

            $("#btnAdd").click(function() {
                addRow($("#tblData"), myEmptyRow,myButtons, $("#tblData tbody tr td").length == 1 ? true : false);
            });

            $('#tblData').on('click', '.btn-save', function() {
                saveRow($(this).closest("tr"));
            });

            $('#tblData').on('click', '.btn-danger, .btn-cancel', function() {
                // registering function for delete button
                deleteStore("row-" + $(this).closest("tr").index());
                $(this).closest("tr").remove();
                if ($("#tblData tbody tr").length == 0) {
                addRow($("#tblData "));
                }
            });

            $('#tblData').on('click', '.btn-edit', function() {
                var row = $(this).closest("tr");
                $(".tdID", row).html("<input type='text' value='" + $(".tdID", row).html() + "' class='form-control txtID' />");
                $(".tdName", row).html("<input type='text' value='" + $(".tdName", row).html() + "' class='form-control txtName' />");
                $(".tdAddress", row).html("<input type='text' value='" + $(".tdAddress", row).html() + "' class='form-control txtAddress' />");
                $(".tdAge", row).html("<input type='text' value='" + $(".tdAge", row).html() + "' class='form-control txtAge' />");
                $(".tdAction", row).html(myButtons.update);
            });
                    
        });

    </script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This took some fixing but I managed to get it to work

please see the example here: https://jsfiddle.net/PatrickHume/tnp89ocx/2/

**PLEASE NOTE** The below stackoverflow example will NOT work because localStorage doesn't work in stackoverflow's code runner due to permissions and it being an embeded iframe, I put it there so you and others can easily see the code

```js
$(function() {
  let myEmptyRow = []
  let myButtons = {};

  function getNewButtons() {
    myButtons = {
      edit: [
        $("<button>", {
          class: "btn btn-success btn-sm btn-edit"
        }).html("Edit"),
        $("<button>", {
          class: "btn btn-danger btn-sm"
        }).html("Delete")
      ],
      update: [
        $("<button>", {
          class: "btn btn-success btn-sm btn-save"
        }).html("Update"),
        $("<button>", {
          class: "btn btn-danger btn-sm"
        }).html("Delete")
      ]
    }
  }

  function getNewEmptyRow() {
    myEmptyRow = [{
      class: "tdID",
      content: $("<input>", {
        type: "text",
        class: "form-control txtID"
      })
    }, {
      class: "tdName",
      content: $("<input>", {
        type: "text",
        class: "form-control txtName"
      })
    }, {
      class: "tdAddress",
      content: $("<input>", {
        type: "text",
        class: "form-control txtAddress"
      })
    }, {
      class: "tdAge",
      content: $("<input>", {
        type: "text",
        class: "form-control txtAge"
      })
    }, {
      class: "tdAction",
      content: [
        $("<button>", {
          class: "btn btn-sm btn-success btn-save"
        }).html("Save"),
        $("<button>", {
          class: "btn btn-sm btn-success btn-cancel"
        }).html("Delete")
      ]
    }]
  }

  function getStore(index) {
    console.log("Get data for " + index);
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(index));
  }

  function saveStore(index, data) {
    console.log("Saving Data to " + index) //, data);
    localStorage.setItem(index, JSON.stringify(data));
  }

  function deleteStore(index) {
    console.log("Deleting Data for " + index);
    localStorage.removeItem(index);
  }

  function addRow(target, data, empty) {
    debugger;
    getNewButtons();
    getNewEmptyRow();
    if (target == undefined) {
      target = $("table:eq(0)");
    }
    if (empty == undefined) {
      empty = false;
    }
    if (data == null) {
      return false;
    }
    console.log("Add Row to " + target.attr("id")) //, empty);
    if (empty && $("tbody tr").length === 0) {
      $("tbody", target).html("");
    }
    var row = $("<tr>").appendTo($("tbody", target));
    if (data == undefined) {
      // Add Empty Row
      $("<td>", {
        colspan: 4,
        class: "text-center"
      }).appendTo(row);
    } else {
      row.addClass("trNewRow");
      $.each(data, function(i, cell) {
        $("<td>", {
          class: cell.class
        }).append(cell.content).appendTo(row);
      });
    }

    //console.log(data,data.length);
    if (data.length == 4) {
      $("<td>", {
        class: "tdAction"
      }).append(myButtons.edit).appendTo(row);
    }
    return row;
  }

  function saveRow(row) {
    if (row == undefined) {
      return false;
    }
     getNewButtons();
     getNewEmptyRow();
    debugger
    const rowData = [{
      class: "tdID",
      content: $(".txtID", row).val()
    }, {
      class: "tdName",
      content: $(".txtName", row).val()
    }, {
      class: "tdAddress",
      content: $(".txtAddress", row).val()
    }, {
      class: "tdAge",
      content: $(".txtAge", row).val()
    }];
    $.each(rowData, function(i, c) {
      $("." + c.class, row).html(c.content);
    });
    $(".tdAction", row).html(myButtons.edit);
    saveStore("row-" + row.index(), rowData);
  }

  function init() {
    if (localStorage.length == 0) {
      addRow($("#tblData"));
    } else {
      console.log("Found Local Storage. Rows: " + localStorage.length);
      $.each(localStorage, function(k, o) {
        const rowData = getStore(k);
        //console.log(k, rowData);
        addRow($("#tblData"), rowData);
      });
    }
  }

  init();

  $("#btnAdd").click(function() {
    addRow($("#tblData"), myEmptyRow, myButtons, $("#tblData tbody tr td").length == 1 ? true : false);
  });

  $('#tblData').on('click', '.btn-save', function() {
    saveRow($(this).closest("tr"));
  });

  $('#tblData').on('click', '.btn-danger, .btn-cancel', function() {
    // registering function for delete button
    deleteStore("row-" + $(this).closest("tr").index());
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    if ($("#tblData tbody tr").length == 0) {
      addRow($("#tblData "));
    }
  });

  $('#tblData').on('click', '.btn-edit', function() {
    const row = $(this).closest("tr");
    $(".tdID", row).html("<input type='text' value='" + $(".tdID", row).html() + "' class='form-control txtID' />");
    $(".tdName", row).html("<input type='text' value='" + $(".tdName", row).html() + "' class='form-control txtName' />");
    $(".tdAddress", row).html("<input type='text' value='" + $(".tdAddress", row).html() + "' class='form-control txtAddress' />");
    $(".tdAge", row).html("<input type='text' value='" + $(".tdAge", row).html() + "' class='form-control txtAge' />");
    $(".tdAction", row).html(myButtons.update);
  });

});
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>CRUD Table jQuery</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 text-right">
        <input type="button" id="btnAdd" class="btn btn-primary para" value="Add New" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row pt-3">
      <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 p-2 ">
        <table id="tblData" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
          <thead>
            <tr id="headings">
              <th class="schedule-color heading">ID</th>
              <th class="schedule-color heading">Name</th>
              <th class="schedule-color heading">Address</th>
              <th class="schedule-color heading">Age</th>
              <th class="tdaction">Action</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody class="searchable">
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

I hope this helps

Comment: But what was wrong with the original?

Comment: there were so many tweaks and changes that I had to make I lost track  of them all Also I didnt list them all as didn't want to come across as overly critical, if you want to see the differences then you can use a https://www.diffchecker.com/ to spot the changes

Comment: From that online diff tool it looks like most of the changes are in whitespace, logging, debugger, etc. The only substantial changes I can see are (a) assigning fresh objects to `myEmptyRow` and `myButtons` each time, and (b) `$("tbody tr").length === 0`. Gratuitous changes to code in stackoverflow are a pet peeve of mine. They obscure the important things from OP and other readers, who are often too inexperienced to know what's important and what isn't. I don't see the point anyway. They're unlikely to learn much from the fact that you changed a `var` to `const`. Anyway, here endeth the rant.

Comment: that a fair point, I will take that on board, to be fair I had to go though several iterations or trial and error to get to that point so whilst in the end may it may not look like much as changed, that’s only after i attempted several variations of solution; hence why i lost track but your right i totally agree to aim is to educate people so i sincerely apologise and will endeavour to do better next time i was being lazy so there are no excuses tfo that. im sorry…

Comment: ...I think in the end your right the key was to re generate the array that held the myEmptyRow  and myButtons  html so the values didn’t persist, the changing to const was to ensure values weren’t mutated ..that’s pretty much it I think or as far as I can actually remember

Comment: Going through lots of changes and losing track of them... Yep, been there. Not least in my current task, which takes several sprints.

Comment: yer its a bad habit of mine, I really need to document more but i get lost in code just like Alice in the rabbit hole =/  I think I may be addicted to coding but there aren’t any coding-acholic anonymous support groups out there =S, I think my wife may have left me but I haven’t had a chance to stop debugging to actually check..I may have a real problem lol